# REST API using SessionId throws "not valid for use with the REST API" for Community users

Tags: community, rest-api, api, saml, session

**Following are the steps I am doing:**

1. Get the Salesforce Session ID through SAML Handshake using SAML attributes
2. Trigger REST API using that session ID

> curl https://my-communities.force.com/services/data/v20.0/query/soql_query_here -H "Authorization: Bearer SessionIDHere"

Curl call to the API responds with an error

> [{"message":"This session is not valid for use with the REST API","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

**Note:**

- The issue is specific to Community users
- The issue started happening after 30th Nov 2017
- This has nothing to do with OAuth flow

I am not sure anything has changed from settings or from Salesforce release side, any help with this.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Need answer for this. Someone pls answer

Comment: Obvious, but does the corresponding user Profile have "API Access" permission?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a small change in the SAML custom attribute

Modify the $API.Session_Id attribute to $User.EmptyFormula__c & $Api.Session_ID where $User.EmptyFormula__c is a formula field on user with value

When this is the case we first evaluate $User.EmptyFormula__c and set Entity Id.
*$User.EmptyFormula__c can be any formula, just so long as it's evaluated before $Api.Session_ID"

detailed [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018Bg6)